# How can I transfer a fixed_seed from main.py module to other modules?

Tags: python, random, arguments, argparse, sys

I have been working on a model which has many processes using a random number generator. The first time, I used to call `import random` in every module where it was necessary to use random generated numbers. I used this like `random.Random.seed(1)` and as it is enough to run the model two different times  and get the same results because it generated the "fixed_seed" in the "parameters" module.

The problem is there are many call processes where I need to call the `parameters` module, and it's re-create the `fixed_seed`. In fact, each simulation month gets the same seed for random numbers generator.

So I tried to transfer this `fixed_seed` creation from parameters to the main module, but I couldn't use the sys or argparse libraries to transfer the `fixed_seed`.

My example:

```
############################################
# in the main model
############################################
import argparse
import random

# creating the fixed seed random generator 
fixed_seed = random.Random(0)

# transfering the fixed_seed to other modules
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parsed_args = parser.parse_args(fixed_seed)

###############################################
# importing the fixed_seed in the other module
###############################################
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
fixed_seed = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand where a `parser` gets its arguments from, and what happens when you do a parse.

A parser is not a state machine, so it does not hold information about what it parsed or pass it on to some other parser.

When you call a script, e.g.

```
$ python mycode.py one two three
```

the shell and interpreter split that commandline into strings and set the `sys.argv` variable

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

should show:

```
['mycode', 'one', 'two', 'three]
```

The first string is the `prog` name, the rest, `sys.argv[1:]` is parsed.

So

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

is the same as

```
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

and in this case

```
args = parser.parse_args(['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

With that in mind, consider this line:

```
parsed_args = parser.parse_args(fixed_seed)
```

You defined `fixed_seed` as `random.Random(0)`.  That's a random number generator (an object) seeded with `0`.  It is not a list of strings like `sys.argv`.  I'm sure that produces an error

I suspect you are trying to save `fixed_seed` in some place that another use of `argparse` will find.  That's not how `argparse` is used.

=========================

You could set the random seed with any `hashable`, including a string.  So if you do `x = random.Random('onetwo')` in two different processes, `x.random()` will generate the same random numbers.

So `argparse` could be used this way:

```
import argparse
import random

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('seed')
args = parser.parse_args()
x = random.Random(args.seed)
for _ in range(3):
    print x.random()
```

and as long as you give each call the same 'seed' word the random numbers should be the same.

```
1926:~/mypy$ python stack37892221.py one
0.438175178474
0.0834683812319
0.43595707944
1926:~/mypy$ python stack37892221.py one
0.438175178474
0.0834683812319
0.43595707944
1926:~/mypy$ python stack37892221.py two
0.183364783476
0.195633546206
0.877462699471
```

If instead of passing a `seed` string around, you need to pass a `Random` object, you might be able to save it via `Pickle`, and load it from that file.

https://pymotw.com/2/random/#saving-state

talks about using `pickle` to save `x.getstate()` for use in another process.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj my necessity is exactly this. I need to generate the "fixed_seed" in the main module, and use that in more 7 modules where is necessary. 

So, how can I do?

      # in the main model
      import random

      # creating the fixed seed random generator 
      fixed_seed = random.Random(0)

       # importing the fixed_seed in the other module
       import sys
       fixed_seed = sys.argv[1]

Comment: See my new `saving-state` link.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj!!!
It's work fine, and solve my problem!
I create a random state in the main, pickle, and load for the first time in each module. After that, in the other months in the simulation, each module dump and load their own "state" of random seed!
Cheers!